# Sprawling locomotion, are knee/elbow joints perpendicular to erect locomotion?

Tags: evolution, zoology, locomotion

The first terrestrial animals used sprawling locomotion. Is the knee and elbow jointed perpendicular to the joints in erect locomotion? It is easy to assume so, based on how the limbs move in sprawling locomotion.

[image]

There was a question on exactly what is meant with jointed perpendicularly. It means the joint angle is perpendicular. Here is a rough ugly sketch, does not have to be a joint like that, question is if the movement in the joint is in any way in that direction.

[image]

Here, Baier seem to support that the knee and elbow joint in sprawling locomotion supports movement perpendicular to the simple hinge joint in erect locomotion, which is exactly what question is asking.

> "The elbow was not a simple hinge; motion entailed substantial
> abduction/adduction"

*Baier, D. B., & Gatesy, S. M. (2013). Three-dimensional skeletal kinematics of the shoulder girdle and forelimb in walkingAlligator. Journal of Anatomy, n/a–n/a. doi:10.1111/joa.12102*

Edit: the "diagram" caused some controversy in comment section. It was a copy+paste, simplest fastest possible I could make, in response to comment *"What do you mean by "jointed perpendicular"?"*, because I considered that comment to be asking something that is clear. It is meant to show the *perpendicular movement direction*, not the joint design. It is not needed for the question, at all.

Comment: They don't appear to be in the images, why do you think that they would be?

Comment: It is easy to assume so, based on how the limbs move in sprawling locomotion. In that particular image, they are jointed perpendicular, but it is a rough schematic, could be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "jointed perpendicular"? They appear to be jointed in the same orientation in both pictures.

Comment: What do these diagrams have to do with the comparison in the original images?

Comment: They were a response to your comment. But nevermind. If you could falsify that abduction/adduction in the elbow joint of alligators is not the perpendicular movement I ask about (since besides flexion/extension, and pronation/supination, it is what is left..), then you prove my question to be wrong. I would guess it is correct though. If it is correct, why are you critiquing it so much?

Comment: A *question* is not correct or wrong, only an answer can be. I am critiquing because it is unclear. Probably it is just an issue of writing it in English, but that's still important because you won't get good answers if the question is unclear. In the diagram you drew, it seems like you are calling "perpendicular" motion to be the hinge-like motion you indicate in green, but when you write "perpendicular to the simple hinge" it sounds like you mean motion *not* in the direction indicated in green.

Comment: But it isn't unclear. Forget the diagram. You were asking questions, "What do you mean by "jointed perpendicular"?" it was a response to that, nevermind it. The question is clear. I suggest the answer by Baier, that there is significant adduction/abduction movement, means that there is *some* perpendicular movement. This means my assumption was right.

Comment: Probably the simplest source of lack of clarity is that you wrote "are knee/elbow joints perpendicular to erect locomotion?" when it seems you meant to ask "can knee/elbow joints move in a direction that is not the primary hinge direction?" These are not interchangeable questions.

Comment: This question could be better explained, perpendicular to a previous orientation? what the migration of the joint and bone orientation is through evolution? perperdicular is a very specific word which requires more specific references to it's surroundings than you give. Are you saying that the knee could fit image 4 rather than image 3?

Answer (score 0):

This article by Baier seem to support that the knee and elbow joint in sprawling locomotion supports movement perpendicular to the simple hinge joint in erect locomotion, which is exactly what question is asking. The joints in sprawlers also supports flexion/extension axis though, and the question could have been a bit clearer on that. If I misinterpret Baier feel free to point that out (but since besides flexion/extension, and pronation/supination, it is what is left, I think I do not), and if not, question answered.

> *"The elbow was not a simple hinge; motion entailed substantial abduction/adduction"*

**References**

Baier, D. B., & Gatesy, S. M. (2013). Three-dimensional skeletal kinematics of the shoulder girdle and forelimb in walkingAlligator. Journal of Anatomy, n/a–n/a. doi:10.1111/joa.12102